# Optimizing function using optimize function

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I want to define a function :

[image]

And I want to find minimum with respect to (a,b) for points :

```
x = np.array([.2, .5, .8, .9, 1.3, 1.7, 2.1, 2.7])
y = f(x) + np.random.randn(len(x))
```

Using function : optimize.fmin_cg (you can find documentation here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html)

**My work so far**

I managed to define a `compute_error()` function :

```
def compute_error(a,b):
    k=[0]*len(x)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        k[i]=(y[i]-(a*x[i]+b))**2
    return sum(k)
```

And I tried to minimize it using this optimize function, however I met some problems.

```
x_0=np.array((0,0))     #start optimization from point (0,0)
 
minimum = optimize.fmin_cg(compute_error,x_0)

TypeError: compute_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think compute_error should take a two-element array not two separate arguments

```
def compute_error(params_to_optimize):
    a = params_to_optimize[0]
    b = params_to_optimize[1]
    k=[0]*len(x)
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        k[i]=(y[i]-(a*x[i]+b))**2
    return sum(k)
```

also, possibly related, x0 initialization looks a bit weird I would use a list not a tuple in the np.array constructor

```
x_0=np.array([0,0])
```

Comment: Two style remarks: 1) you can write `a, b = params_to_optimize` to unpack the tuple, instead of the two first lines 2) instead of the `for` loop you can use vector form (for `numpy` it is generally faster) `k = (y - (a*x + b))**2`. This way your code will be more readable, concise and error prone.